# Creating a spline curve between 2 points in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to link points with a spline using Three.js for a visualization I'm trying to make.

As far as I can tell, I add points to an array, pass that to THREE.SplineCurve3, step through the spline points to get the geom coords and render.  It works if I only add the start/end points to the array but if I try to add a mid-point, I get an error.

Example is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/sLQK9/4/

I'm sure it's something simple but I can't spot it - can anyone help me?

Ultimately, the points will be on the surface of a sphere and the splines between 2 points will take the route an aircraft would take - I.E. sort of great circle but further away from the center of the sphere at the midpoint of the spline.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

I think you need to specify how many points you want the spline to interpolate the curve with, although you are specifying `control` points, the curve doesn't know how smooth you want it.

Try something like this:

```
// smooth my curve over this many points
var numPoints = 100;

spline = new THREE.SplineCurve3([
   new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
   new THREE.Vector3(0, 200, 0),
   new THREE.Vector3(150, 150, 0),
   new THREE.Vector3(150, 50, 0),
   new THREE.Vector3(250, 100, 0),
   new THREE.Vector3(250, 300, 0)
]);

var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xff00f0,
});

var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var splinePoints = spline.getPoints(numPoints);

for(var i = 0; i < splinePoints.length; i++){
    geometry.vertices.push(splinePoints[i]);  
}

var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
scene.add(line);
```

Then, as pointed out in @juan Mellado answer, you can get a position on the line using `spline.getPoint(t)` where t is value between `0-1`, start and end points of the spline.

As an aside, see a recent [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179327/orient-objects-rotation-to-a-spline-point-tangent-in-three-js) that was answered for me, which includes the example above.

Comment: Also, thinking about your project, you could use the vertices from your sphere as control points for the spline!

Answer (score 9):

My solution for making curves between two point in 3D scene, especially on globe:

```
var createCurvePath = function(start, end, elevation) {
    var start3 = globe.translateCordsToPoint(start.latitude, start.longitude);
    var end3 = globe.translateCordsToPoint(end.latitude, end.longitude);
    var mid = (new LatLon(start.latitude, start.longitude)).midpointTo(new LatLon(end.latitude, end.longitude));
    var middle3 = globe.translateCordsToPoint(mid.lat(), mid.lon(), elevation);

    var curveQuad = new THREE.QuadraticBezierCurve3(start3, middle3, end3);
    //   var curveCubic = new THREE.CubicBezierCurve3(start3, start3_control, end3_control, end3);

    var cp = new THREE.CurvePath();
    cp.add(curveQuad);
    //   cp.add(curveCubic);
    return cp;
}
```

then call it:

```
var cp = globe.createCurvePath(item1, item2, 200);
var curvedLineMaterial =  new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: 0xFFFFAA, linewidth: 3});
var curvedLine = new THREE.Line(cp.createPointsGeometry(20), curvedLineMaterial);
globe.scene.add(curvedLine);
```

note Quadratic or Cubic method of curve creation
[image: Quadratic vs Cubic Beizer]

Comment: I have the exact same use case but I was wondering how the commented code is calculated. For the Cubic curves. How do you proceed to compute start3_control and end3_control?

Comment: I have some problems with calculating the correct coordinates too. Feel free do some experiments and find your correct config, finally I have chosen the Quadratic method... See it working on http://vis.jaik.sk/ (unmaintained school project) also check http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: https://medium.com/@xiaoyangzhao/drawing-curves-on-webgl-globe-using-three-js-and-d3-draft-7e782ffd7ab

Answer (score 3):

The parameter of `getPoint` must be in range [0..1]:

```
// Virtual base class method to overwrite and implement in subclasses
//  - t [0 .. 1]

THREE.Curve.prototype.getPoint = function ( t ) {
...
```