# ThreeJS animation in 2D constant speed - following a bezier curve

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have this bezier curves that represent my flow of some particles. The problem is that I cannot seem to control the speed of the object unless I add more points on the bezier curve but that is inefficient..

[image]

These are my curves.

And my code is simply (in the `animate()` method):

```
function moveParticlesAlongCurve(particles,curvePoints){
  particles[0].position.x = curvePoints[i].x;
  particles[0].position.y = curvePoints[i].y;
  i++;
}
```

Any ideas on how to control the speed?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400667/three-js-object-following-a-spline-path-rotation-tanget-issues-constant-sp/18409167#18409167

Comment: thanks man I had to use  .getPointAt( t ) instead of .getPoint( t ).

Answer (score 0):

I image `moveParticlesAlongCurve` is called continuously and `i` is defined somewhere outside, you can try incrementing `i` inside a `setTimeout` to delay the next tick, see if that helps.

```
    function moveParticlesAlongCurve(particles,curvePoints){
      particles[0].position.x = curvePoints[i].x;
      particles[0].position.y = curvePoints[i].y;
      setTimeout(function(){ i++; }, 1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To maintain a constant speed, you should use `curve.getPointAt( t )` instead of `curve.getPoint( t )`.

There is more detail in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400667/three-js-object-following-a-spline-path-rotation-tanget-issues-constant-sp/18409167#18409167) to a related question.

three.js r.91