# How to extrude different shapes on the same spline without interruptions

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm writing a scene with meshes generated with *ExtrudeGeometry* from different shapes extruded along a *SplineCurve3* used as *extrudePath* in *ExtrudeGeometry*'s settings.

For now, to do that, I split the spline in many segments, but there is a problem, as you can see in the attached picture:

[image: detail]

I want the starting point of second mesh (star) to be perpendicular to the end point of previous mesh (circle).

Here my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mitma/9B4kn/).

Now as you can see in the picture and in the demo, the star does not start perpendicular to circle shape.

I found [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1810) topic, which seems to describe the same situation, and I read these answers: [one](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1810#issuecomment-5341975), [two](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1810#issuecomment-5356042).

So, probably, reading the last [second](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1810#issuecomment-5356042) link, I need to know the angle between tangent and up-vector (= Y) at level of the last point on spline_1, and apply that angle for a rotation on binormal of shape used with spline_2, before extrude it, and perhaps for this I need to use the "frames" option in ExtrudeGeometry... but I have not found any example about how to pass binormal vector in frames option... I found instead [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179327/orient-objects-rotation-to-a-spline-point-tangent-in-three-js) page to understand how calculate tangents and binormals, to fill my knowledge; in my case, I need to align the shape (star) in the first frame of spline_2 with the shape (circle) in the last frame of spline_1; so, probably I need to know the angle between the tangent and the up-vector on last point of spline_1, and apply that angle for a rotation on binormal of first frame of spline_2... so I tried to add the follow before add meshes to the scene:

```
var tangent, axis, up, radians;
var t = 1; // last point of spline_1
tangent = spline_1.getTangent( t ).normalize(); // tangent unit on last point of spline_1, which I need to pass as tangent for the first point of spline_2
up = new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0); // set up-vector equal to Y axis
radians = Math.acos( up.dot( tangent ) ); // angle between up-vector and tangent in last point of spline_1, to be applied on binormal of spline_2 at its first frame
axis = new THREE.Vector3(); // create a new vector for binormal (= rotation axis)
axis.crossVectors( up, tangent ).normalize(); // binormal equal to cross product between up and tangent vectors of spline_1, which I need to pass as binormal for the first point of spline_2
```

but now how to rotate only the first frame of spline_2, instead of apply rotation to all the extruded star mesh?... Maybe using frames option in [ExtrudeGeometry](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Geometries/ExtrudeGeometry)?

As alternative approach, is then possible to use segments of a unique spline to extrude different shapes (avoiding probably the above problem), as [@WestLangley](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1810#issuecomment-5341975) suggested? For example, following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165607/creating-a-spline-curve-between-2-points-in-three-js) topic, I tried to use "t" as reference to set position on a unique spline, but without success; consider:

```
// Catmull-Rom spline (SplineCurve3)
// t = (point number) / (number of points - 1)
var spline = new THREE.SplineCurve3([
    new THREE.Vector3(7.67, 279.32, 904.50), // t = 0
    new THREE.Vector3(21.48, 265.57, 937.23), // t = 1/23
    new THREE.Vector3(57.94, 254.71, 934.70), // t = 2/23
    new THREE.Vector3(49.16, 217.44, 935.41), // t = 3/23
    new THREE.Vector3(28.10, 221.71, 903.81), // t = 4/23
    new THREE.Vector3(51.95, 247.45, 888.89), // t = 5/23
    new THREE.Vector3(71.82, 240.66, 857.35), // t = 6/23
    new THREE.Vector3(100.53, 261.25, 871.66), // t = 7/23
    new THREE.Vector3(107.88, 249.14, 907.15), // t = 8/23
    new THREE.Vector3(138.08, 227.01, 908.38), // t = 9/23
    new THREE.Vector3(155.60, 208.83, 937.33), // t = 10/23
    new THREE.Vector3(186.68, 228.31, 947.35), // t = 11/23
    new THREE.Vector3(206.93, 195.57, 943.90), // t = 12/23
    new THREE.Vector3(203.43, 198.27, 906.12), // t = 13/23
    new THREE.Vector3(227.68, 227.35, 907.16), // t = 14/23
    new THREE.Vector3(264.72, 231.83, 910.87), // t = 15/23
    new THREE.Vector3(277.70, 267.24, 914.58), // t = 16/23
    new THREE.Vector3(312.24, 269.76, 898.61), // t = 17/23
    new THREE.Vector3(323.17, 305.65, 893.96), // t = 18/23
    new THREE.Vector3(310.66, 337.84, 909.49), // t = 19/23
    new THREE.Vector3(307.87, 363.10, 881.36), // t = 20/23
    new THREE.Vector3(293.54, 391.54, 901.52), // t = 21/23
    new THREE.Vector3(284.14, 402.13, 936.36), // t = 22/23
    new THREE.Vector3(265.69, 431.90, 950.82) // t = 23/23 = 1
]);

for( var t = 0; t < 0.5; t++) {
    var spline_1 = spline.getPoints(t); // to be used as extrudePath with shape_1 for ExtrudeGeometry
}

for( var t = 0.5; t <= 1; t++) {
    var spline_2 = spline.getPoints(t); // to be used as extrudePath with shape_2 for ExtrudeGeometry
}
```

But it's not good.

I ask you a help to solve this issue...

I'm happy to start understanding and merging all found sources, but there is not an improvement. I would be happy for your help.

Many thanks in advance,

Greetings,

Riccardo

**# EDIT 1**

Found the way to split a unique spline in segments, and apply them as extrudePath for each shape, but I obtain the same result:

[Test 2](http://jsfiddle.net/mitma/46Lfy/)