# Three.js - How to use the frames option in ExtrudeGeometry

Tags: three.js

I can't find anywhere an explaination about how to use the *frames* option for ExtrudeGeometry in Three.js. Its [documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Geometries/ExtrudeGeometry) says:

```
extrudePath — THREE.CurvePath. 3d spline path to extrude shape along. (creates Frames if (frames aren't defined)

frames — THREE.TubeGeometry.FrenetFrames. containing arrays of tangents, normals, binormals
```

but I don't understand how *frames* must be defined. I think using the "frames" option, passing three arrays for tangents, normals and binormals (calculated in some way), but how to pass them in *frames*?... Probably (like [here](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Geometry) for *morphNormals*):

```
    frames = { tangents: [ new THREE.Vector3(), ... ], normals: [ new THREE.Vector3(), ... ], binormals: [ new THREE.Vector3(), ... ] };
```

with the three arrays of the same lenght (perhaps corresponding to *steps* or *curveSegments* option in ExtrudeGeometry)?

Many thanks for an explanation.

**Edit 1**:

```
String.prototype.format = function () {
    var str = this;
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        str = str.replace('{' + i + '}', arguments[i]);
    }
    return str;
}

var numSegments = 6;
var frames = new THREE.TubeGeometry.FrenetFrames( new THREE.SplineCurve3(spline), numSegments );
var tangents = frames.tangents,
    normals = frames.normals,
    binormals = frames.binormals;

var tangents_list = [],
    normals_list = [],
    binormals_list = [];
for ( i = 0; i < numSegments; i++ ) {
    var tangent = tangents[ i ];
    var normal = normals[ i ];
    var binormal = binormals[ i ];
    tangents_list.push("({0}, {1}, {2})".format(tangent.x, tangent.y, tangent.z));
    normals_list.push("({0}, {1}, {2})".format(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z));
    binormals_list.push("({0}, {1}, {2})".format(binormal.x, binormal.y, binormal.z));
}
alert(tangents_list);
alert(normals_list);
alert(binormals_list);
```

**Edit 2**

Times ago, I opened [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520158/how-to-extrude-different-shapes-on-the-same-spline-without-interruptions) topic for which I used [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mitma/8uoevw0z/) solution:

```
var spline = new THREE.SplineCurve3([
    new THREE.Vector3(20.343, 19.827, 90.612),  // t=0
    new THREE.Vector3(22.768, 22.735, 90.716),  // t=1/12
    new THREE.Vector3(26.472, 23.183, 91.087),  // t=2/12
    new THREE.Vector3(27.770, 26.724, 91.458),  // t=3/12
    new THREE.Vector3(31.224, 26.976, 89.861),  // t=4/12
    new THREE.Vector3(32.317, 30.565, 89.396),  // t=5/12
    new THREE.Vector3(31.066, 33.784, 90.949),  // t=6/12
    new THREE.Vector3(30.787, 36.310, 88.136),  // t=7/12
    new THREE.Vector3(29.354, 39.154, 90.152),  // t=8/12
    new THREE.Vector3(28.414, 40.213, 93.636),  // t=9/12
    new THREE.Vector3(26.569, 43.190, 95.082),  // t=10/12
    new THREE.Vector3(24.237, 44.399, 97.808),  // t=11/12
    new THREE.Vector3(21.332, 42.137, 96.826)   // t=12/12=1
]);

var spline_1 = [], spline_2 = [], t;

for( t = 0; t <= (7/12); t+=0.0001) {
    spline_1.push(spline.getPoint(t));
}

for( t = (7/12); t <= 1; t+=0.0001) {
    spline_2.push(spline.getPoint(t));
}
```

But I was thinking the possibility to set the tangent, normal and binormal for the first point (t=0) of spline_2 to be the same of last point (t=1) of spline_1; so I thought if that option, frames, could return in some way useful for the purpose. Could be possible to overwrite the value for a tangent, normal and binormal in the respective list, to obtain the same value for the last point (t=1) of *spline_1* and the first point (t=0) of *spline_2*, so to guide the extrusion? For example, for the tangent at "t=0" of *spline_2*:

```
tangents[0].x = 0.301;
tangents[0].y = 0.543;
tangents[0].z = 0.138;
```

doing the same also for *normals[0]* and *binormals[0]*, to ensure the same orientation for the last point (t=1) of *spline_1* and the first one (t=0) of *spline_2*

**Edit 3**

I'm trying to visualize the *tangent*, *normal* and *binormal* for each control point of "*mypath*" (spline) using *ArrowHelper*, but, as you can see in the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mitma/8uoevw0z/2/) (on scene loading, you need zoom out the scene slowly, until you see the ArrowHelpers, to find them. The relative code starts from line 122 to line 152 in the fiddle), the ArrowHelper does not start at origin, but away from it. How to obtain the same result of [this](http://jabtunes.com/labs/3d/webgl_geometry_extrude_splines.html) reference demo  (when you check the "Debug normals" checkbox)?

**Edit 4**

[image: Tangents, normals, binormals]

I plotted two splines that respectively end (blue spline) and start (red spline) at point A (= origin), displaying tangent, normal and binormal vectors at point A for each spline (using cyan color for the blue spline's labels, and yellow color for the red spline's labels).

As mentioned above, to align and make continuous the two splines, I thought to exploit the three vectors (tangent, normal and binormal). Which mathematical operation, in theory, should I use to turn the end face of blue spline in a way that it views the initial face (yellow face) of red spline, so that the respective tangents (D, D'-hidden in the picture), normals (B, B') and binormals (C, C') are aligned? Should I use the ".setFromUnitVectors (vFrom, VTO)" method of quaternion? In its [documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Quaternion) I read: << Sets this quaternion to the rotation required to rotate vFrom direction vector to vector direction VTO ... vFrom VTO and are assumed to be normalized. >> So, probably, I need to define three quaternions:

1. quaternion for the rotation of the normalized tangent D vector in the direction of the normalized tangent D' vector
2. quaternion for the rotation of the normalized normal B vector in the direction of the normalized normal B' vector
3. quaternion for the rotation of the normalized binormal C vector in the direction of the normalized binormal C' vector

with:

- *vFrom* = normalized D, B and C vectors
- *VTO* ​​= normalized D', B' and C' vectors

and apply each of the three quaternions respectively to D, B and C (not normalized)?

Thanks a lot again

**Edit 5**

I tried this code (looking in the image how to align the vectors) but nothing has changed:

```
var numSegments_1 = points_1.length; // points_1 = list of points
var frames_1 = new THREE.TubeGeometry.FrenetFrames( points_1_spline, numSegments_1, false ); // path, segments, closed
var tangents_1 = frames_1.tangents,
    normals_1 = frames_1.normals,
    binormals_1 = frames_1.binormals;

var numSegments_2 = points_2.length;
var frames_2 = new THREE.TubeGeometry.FrenetFrames( points_2_spline, numSegments_2, false );
var tangents_2 = frames_2.tangents,
    normals_2 = frames_2.normals,
    binormals_2 = frames_2.binormals;

var b1_b2_angle = binormals_1[ binormals_1.length - 1 ].angleTo( binormals_2[ 0 ] ); // angle between binormals_1 (at point A of spline 1) and binormals_2 (at point A of spline 2)
var quaternion_n1_axis = new THREE.Quaternion();
quaternion_n1_axis.setFromAxisAngle( normals_1[ normals_1.length - 1 ], b1_b2_angle ); // quaternion equal to a rotation on normal_1 as axis
var vector_b1 = binormals_1[ binormals_1.length - 1 ];
vector_b1.applyQuaternion( quaternion_n1_axis ); // apply quaternion to binormals_1

var n1_n2_angle = normals_1[ normals_1.length - 1 ].angleTo( normals_2[ 0 ] ); // angle between normals_1 (at point A of spline 1) and normals_2 (at point A of spline 2)
var quaternion_b1_axis = new THREE.Quaternion();
quaternion_b1_axis.setFromAxisAngle( binormals_1[ binormals_1.length - 1 ], -n1_n2_angle ); // quaternion equal to a rotation on binormal_1 as axis
var vector_n1 = normals_1[ normals_1.length - 1 ];
vector_n1.applyQuaternion( quaternion_b1_axis ); // apply quaternion to normals_1
```

nothing in this other way also:

```
var numSegments_1 = points_1.length; // points_1 = list of points
var frames_1 = new THREE.TubeGeometry.FrenetFrames( points_1_spline, numSegments_1, false ); // path, segments, closed
var tangents_1 = frames_1.tangents,
    normals_1 = frames_1.normals,
    binormals_1 = frames_1.binormals;

var numSegments_2 = points_2.length;
var frames_2 = new THREE.TubeGeometry.FrenetFrames( points_2_spline, numSegments_2, false );
var tangents_2 = frames_2.tangents,
    normals_2 = frames_2.normals,
    binormals_2 = frames_2.binormals;

var quaternion_n1_axis = new THREE.Quaternion();
quaternion_n1_axis.setFromUnitVectors( binormals_1[ binormals_1.length - 1 ].normalize(), binormals_2[ 0 ].normalize() );
var vector_b1 = binormals_1[ binormals_1.length - 1 ];
vector_b1.applyQuaternion( quaternion_n1_axis );

var quaternion_b1_axis = new THREE.Quaternion();
quaternion_b1_axis.setFromUnitVectors( normals_1[ normals_1.length - 1 ].normalize(), normals_2[ 0 ].normalize() );
var vector_n1 = normals_1[ normals_1.length - 1 ];
vector_n1.applyQuaternion( quaternion_b1_axis );
```

Comment: Try this: `frames = new THREE.TubeGeometry.FrenetFrames( path, numSegments )`. You may have to study the source code.

Comment: @WestLangley, thanks a lot! Look in my *edit 1* for the used code: I saw the source code of *TubeGeometry.js* file (http://code.google.com/r/vahidrezamousavi-ozclone/source/browse/website/js/vendor/three/src/extras/geometries/TubeGeometry.js?r=1bcfbb0d09759d11ea734d3d0a11902568df7751#46), at line 46.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @WestLangley, I added an *edit 2*

Comment: Sure, why not? Give it a try. You are just going to have to study the source code.

Comment: @WestLangley, I added an *edit 3*. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, I can't debug your code for you. Remove the mesh recentering. http://jsfiddle.net/8uoevw0z/4/

Comment: @WestLangley, sorry. I have seen the differences (https://www.diffchecker.com/) you've made, thank you so much.

Comment: @WestLangley, I added an *edit 4*. I should be grateful if you would kindly have a look, thanks a lot

Comment: The joints are going to look terrible, anyway. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: To draw two continuous splines, in a quite perfect way, better than using this method (http://jsfiddle.net/mitma/8uoevw0z/)...

Comment: @WestLangley, added an *edit 5*

Comment: I would suggest you find another approach. Either create 1 spline from all your data, or modify `TubeGeometry` to accept an initial Frenet frame. Sorry, I can't help you with your code. I hope you understand.

Comment: Don't worry, thank you anyway for suggestions, they are important too! Happy Easter :-)