# Is there a way to set the initial shape orientation for ExtrudeBufferGeometrie along a path in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, orientation

I want to extrude a `shape` along an `extrudePath` using `THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry()`.

Basically this works fine, but the initial shape orientation is arbitrary, due to FrenetFrames as answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626171/threejs-extrudegeometry-depth-gives-different-result-than-extrudepath).
The extrudePath is lying on one plane, so there will never be a problem regarding closing the Extrusion due to "wrong" orientation.

```
var myExtrudePath = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3( <some THREE.Vector3() vectors> );

var shape = new THREE.Shape();
shape.lineTo( ... );
...

var extrudeSettings = { extrudePath: myExtrudePath };

var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );
```

Is there a way to set the initial shape orientation manually?

---

**EDIT 1**

I would like to avoid editing the three.js-File. I found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390462/three-js-how-to-use-the-frames-option-in-extrudegeometry). Is it (still) possible to give normal-vectors or frames as options to the ExtrudeBufferGeometry() ?

I imagine something like:

```
var phi = Math.PI / 2;
var normal = new THREE.Vector3( Math.sin(phi), Math.cos(phi), 0);
var binormal = new THREE.Vector3( Math.cos(phi), Math.sin(phi), 0);
var frames = { normals: [normal, normal], binormals: [binormal, binormal] };

var extrudeSettings = {
    steps: 100,
    extrudePath: path,
    frames: frames
}

var geometry = new THREE.ExtrudeBufferGeometry( shape, extrudeSettings );
```

This does not work so far. I get an Error in three.js:2582:4 :

> TypeError: v is undefined
>
> > copy
> >     ExtrudeBufferGeometry.prototype.addShape
> >     ExtrudeBufferGeometry.prototype.addShapeList
> >     ExtrudeBufferGeometry

Comment: You have to hack the library. In `curve.js`, search for the code block `// select an initial normal` and hardwire the computed normal to whatever you want: `normal.set( x, y, z ).normalize();`

Comment: @WestLangley Is it possible to give normal vectors as an option to ExtrudeBufferGeometry() ? (See EDIT 1 above)

Comment: The best answer I can give you now is for you to redefine `computeFrenetFrames()` in your application: `THREE.Curve.prototype.computeFrenetFrames = function( segments, closed ) { ... };`