# Cubic Bezier Curve between two points on a sphere in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, bezier

I'm letting the user click on two points on a sphere and I would then like to draw a line between the two points along the surface of the sphere (basically on the great circle). I've been able to get the coordinates of the two selected points and draw a `QuadraticBezierCurve3` between the points, but I need to be using `CubicBezierCurve3`. The problem is is that I have no clue how to find the two control points.

Part of the issue is everything I find is for circular arcs and only deals with [x,y] coordinates (whereas I'm working with [x,y,z]). I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165607/creating-a-spline-curve-between-2-points-in-three-js) other question which I used to get a somewhat-working solution using `QuadraticBezierCurve3`. I've found numerous other pages with math/code like [this](http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wiki/index.php/Circular_arc_approximation_by_cubic_Bezier_curve), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37512/find-sagitta-of-a-cubic-b%C3%A9zier-described-arc), and [this](http://syedrezaali.com/MAT/594CM/research.html), but I really just don't know what to apply. Something else I came across mentioned the tangents (to the selected points), their intersection, and their midpoints. But again, I'm unsure of how to do that in 3D space (since the tangent can go in more than one direction, i.e. a plane).

An example of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/GhB82/

To draw the line, I'm using:

```
function drawLine(point) {
   var middle = [(pointA['x'] + pointB['x']) / 2, (pointA['y'] + pointB['y']) / 2, (pointA['z'] + pointB['z']) / 2];
   var curve = new THREE.QuadraticBezierCurve3(new THREE.Vector3(pointA['x'], pointA['y'], pointA['z']), new THREE.Vector3(middle[0], middle[1], middle[2]), new THREE.Vector3(pointB['x'], pointB['y'], pointB['z']));
   var path = new THREE.CurvePath();
   path.add(curve);
   var curveMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
      color: 0xFF0000
   });
   curvedLine = new THREE.Line(path.createPointsGeometry(20), curveMaterial);
   scene.add(curvedLine);
}
```

Where pointA and pointB are arrays containing the [x,y,z] coordinates of the selected points on the sphere. I need to change the `QuadraticBezierCurve3` to `CubicBezierCurve3`, but again, I'm really at a loss on finding those control points.

Answer (score 2):

I have a description on how to fit cubic curves to circular arcs over at http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#circles_cubic, the 3D case is essentially the same in that you need to find out the (great) circular cross-section your two points form on the sphere, and then build the cubic Bezier section along that circle.

Downside: Unless your arc is less than or equal to roughly a quarter circle, one curve is not going to be enough, you'll need two or more. You can't actually model true circular curves with Bezier curves, so using cubic instead of quadratic just means you can approximate a longer arc segment before it starts to look horribly off.

So on a completely different solution note: if you have an arc command available, much better to use that than to roll your own (and if three.js doesn't support them, definitely worth filing a feature request for, I'd think)